# Parsing dynamically generated JSON object names with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm attempting to deserialize some MediaWiki context from JSON using Jackson into POJOs. However, the problem is that one of the JSON object names is the integer ID value of the article, so using an annotation like `@JsonProperty` can't be used because the value is never constant.

Here's some sample JSON to describe what I mean:

`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=info&format=json&indexpageids`

```
{
    "query": {
        "pageids": [
            "736"
        ],
        "pages": {
            "736": {
                "pageid": 736,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Albert Einstein",
                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                "pagelanguage": "en",
                "touched": "2014-01-05T03:14:23Z",
                "lastrevid": 588780054,
                "counter": "",
                "length": 106159
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(MediaWiki recommends adding the &indexpageids parameter to assist with parsing, however I can't see how it would be useful to me.)

I tried using the `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` annotations as well but they don't appear to help, throwing the same exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "736" (class WikipediaPages), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "wikipediaPage"])`.

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Edit: Here's what the relevant classes look like at the moment:

```
public class WikipediaPages {

    private Map<String, WikipediaPage> wikipediaPageMap = new HashMap<String, WikipediaPage>();

    public Map<String, WikipediaPage> getWikipediaPageMap() {
        return wikipediaPageMap;
    }

    public void setWikipediaPageMap(Map<String, WikipediaPage> wikipediaPageMap) {
        this.wikipediaPageMap = wikipediaPageMap;
    }
}
```

I use a Jackson Mixin to apply annotations:

```
public interface WikipediaPagesMixIn {

    @JsonAnyGetter
    Map<String, WikipediaPage> getWikipediaPageMap();

    @JsonAnySetter
    void setWikipediaPageMap(Map<String, WikipediaPage> wikipediaPageMap);
}
```

Edit 2: More code, as requested:

```
public class JacksonBuilder {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        if(objectMapper == null) {
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.registerModule(new WikipediaModule());
        }

        return objectMapper;
    }
}

public class WikipediaModule extends SimpleModule {

    public WikipediaModule() {
        super("WikipediaModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "net.ryanmorrison", "sentience"));
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext setupContext) {
        setupContext.setMixInAnnotations(WikipediaPage.class, WikipediaPageMixIn.class);
        setupContext.setMixInAnnotations(WikipediaPages.class, WikipediaPagesMixIn.class);
        setupContext.setMixInAnnotations(WikipediaQuery.class, WikipediaQueryMixIn.class);
        setupContext.setMixInAnnotations(WikipediaResult.class, WikipediaResultMixIn.class);
    }
}

public class WikipediaResult {

    private WikipediaQuery wikipediaQuery;

    public WikipediaQuery getWikipediaQuery() {
        return wikipediaQuery;
    }

    public void setWikipediaQuery(WikipediaQuery wikipediaQuery) {
        this.wikipediaQuery = wikipediaQuery;
    }
}

public interface WikipediaResultMixIn {

    @JsonProperty("query")
    WikipediaQuery getWikipediaQuery();
}
```

Comment: Make `pages` a `Map<String, Page>` where `Page` holds all that other data.

Comment: Same exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "38991692" (class WikipediaPages), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "wikipediaPageMap"])`.

Comment: Just edited the original question with relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the root cause of your exception, the `@JsonAnySetter` javadoc states

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static,
>   **two-argument method (first argument name of property, second value to
>   set)**, [...]

As such, using a mixin like this

```
@JsonAnySetter
void setWikipediaPageMap(Map<String, WikipediaPage> wikipediaPageMap);
```

doesn't register it and therefore the property isn't found.

Honestly, don't use mixins if you control the data classes. You can directly map the fields as I've shown below.

---

I don't know how you are using your mixin, but the following works for me

```
String json = "{ \"query\": { \"pageids\": [ \"736\" ], \"pages\": { \"736\": { \"pageid\": 736, \"ns\": 0, \"title\": \"Albert Einstein\", \"contentmodel\": \"wikitext\", \"pagelanguage\": \"en\", \"touched\": \"2014-01-05T03:14:23Z\", \"lastrevid\": 588780054, \"counter\": \"\", \"length\": 106159 } } } }";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node =mapper.readTree(json);

node = node.get("query").get("pages");

Map<String, Page> pages = mapper.readValue(node.traverse(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Page>>() {
});

System.out.println(pages);
```

prints

```
{736=Page [pageid=736, ns=0, title=Albert Einstein, contentmodel=wikitext, pagelanguage=en, touched=2014-01-05T03:14:23Z, lastrevid=588780054, counter=, length=106159]}
```

Where `Page` is

```
class Page {
    private int pageid;
    private int ns;
    private String title;
    private String contentmodel;
    private String pagelanguage;
    private String touched; // this could be a Date, with the appropriate format configuration
    private int lastrevid;
    private String counter;
    private int length;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Page [pageid=" + pageid + ", ns=" + ns + ", title=" + title
                + ", contentmodel=" + contentmodel + ", pagelanguage="
                + pagelanguage + ", touched=" + touched + ", lastrevid="
                + lastrevid + ", counter=" + counter + ", length=" + length
                + "]";
    }
    public int getPageid() {
        return pageid;
    }
    public void setPageid(int pageid) {
        this.pageid = pageid;
    }
    public int getNs() {
        return ns;
    }
    public void setNs(int ns) {
        this.ns = ns;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContentmodel() {
        return contentmodel;
    }
    public void setContentmodel(String contentmodel) {
        this.contentmodel = contentmodel;
    }
    public String getPagelanguage() {
        return pagelanguage;
    }
    public void setPagelanguage(String pagelanguage) {
        this.pagelanguage = pagelanguage;
    }
    public String getTouched() {
        return touched;
    }
    public void setTouched(String touched) {
        this.touched = touched;
    }
    public int getLastrevid() {
        return lastrevid;
    }
    public void setLastrevid(int lastrevid) {
        this.lastrevid = lastrevid;
    }
    public String getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void setCounter(String counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

All that is left is to put the `Map<String, Page>` as a field in some wrapper class for the `query` and `pages` JSON elements.

Comment: If I use the top block of code, it works as well. I'm applying mixins by creating a Jackson module, adding each mixin within the `setupContext` method and applying the module on the `ObjectMapper` instantiation. I'd like to remain consistent with the rest of my JSON deserialization code and solve the original problem though.

Comment: @ryan As far as I can tell, the error happens because Jackson doesn't know how to map the JSON element name `736`. I can't help without seeing how you are doing your deserialization.

Comment: I have 4 model classes, WikipediaResult for the top-level JSON, WikipediaQuery for the "query" object, WikipediaPages for the "pages" object and WikipediaPage for the dynamically named object. I do the deserialization by calling `WikipediaResult wikipediaResult = JacksonBuilder.getObjectMapper().readValue(getInputStreamFromConnection(buildURLFromQuery(query)), WikipediaResult.class)`.  providing an InputStream from a HTTP connection. JacksonBuilder simply instantiates a new `ObjectMapper` instance and adds the module containing the mixins to it.

Comment: @Ryan I can't do anything with that. Show me by editing your question. Show me how you setup your `ObjectMapper`. I'd like to see the `WikipediaResult` as well.

Comment: Sure, I edited the question. Thanks for sticking around to help.